# NGRX store not being populated

Tags: ngrx-store

I am attempting to populate an ngrx store with data queried from an API and formatted by the following code

API service

```
getMaterialImagesByMaterialId(id: string){
    const images: Array<MaterialImage> = new Array<MaterialImage>();
    this.getImageData(id)
      .pipe(
        pluck('value')
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        const postBody = Array<PostBodyItem>();
          for(const img of data) {
            postBody.push({ItemType: "Image", ItemId: img.ImageId});
          }
          this.getImageMedia(postBody).subscribe(media => {
            for(let i = 0; i < media.length; i++) {
              const image: MaterialImage = {
                id: data[i].ImageId,
                createdBy: data[i].AliasUser.FirstName + " " + data[i].AliasUser.LastName,
                title: media[i].Title,
                description: data[i].Description,
                timestamp: data[i].SmpteTime,
                url: media[i].StreamingUrl,
                output: 'FOOBAR'
              };
               images.push(image);
            }
          });
      }
    );
    console.log(images);
    return images;
  }

  private getImageData(id: string) {
    const url = `...`;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('UseBasicAuth', 'true');
    return this.http.get<MaterialImageResponse>(url, {headers})
      .pipe(
        switchMap(data => {
          this.loggerService.log(`Retrieved ${this.entityName}`);
          return of(data);
        }),
        catchError(error => this.handleError(`Retrieving ${this.entityName} Failed`, error))
      );
  }

  private getImageMedia(body: Array<PostBodyItem>){
    const url = '...';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('UseBasicAuth', 'true');
    return this.http.post(url, body, {headers})
      .pipe(
        switchMap(data => {
          this.loggerService.log(`Retrieved ${this.entityName}`);
          return of(data);
        }),
        catchError(error => this.handleError(`Retrieving ${this.entityName} Failed`, error))
      );
  }
```

image.effect

```
@Injectable()
export class MaterialImagesEffects {
  constructor(private materialImagesActions$: Actions, private api$: MaterialImageResource)
  {}

  load$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
    this.materialImagesActions$.pipe(
      ofType(materialImagesActions.LOAD_IMAGES),
      switchMap(action => {
        return [
          materialImagesActions.LOAD_IMAGES_SUCCESS({
            materialImages:this.api$.getMaterialImagesByMaterialId(action.materialId.toString())
          })
        ];
      })
    )
  );
}
```

Anyone have any insight as to why LOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS would be firing but not populating the store with the generated contents?

My best guess is that there is some form of race condition occurring so if that is the case how would I remedy that?

Answer (score -1):

You should never change the store from the effect. Always call an action,that fires effect that calls your Service to fetch the data, and after that you should fire action `LOAD_IMAGES_SUCCESS` in your effect. The reducer should listen to this `SUCCESS` action and modify your store. Look this nice example with Action/Effect/Reducer/Store:

https://www.intertech.com/Blog/ngrx-tutorial-actions-reducers-and-effects/

If you follow it, it should be easy for you to understand the concept.

Comment: From what I can tell what you are suggesting I do is exactly what my code is doing...

Comment: Please make an StackBlitz example so I can have a look. You downvoted my proposal without even giving it a try. As I said already, you are not populating your store from the reducer, not as it looks like in your post. Maybe you did not posted all components? how does your reducer looks like?